# Is it possible to do threaded testing with Arquillian?

Tags: java, multithreading, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to test a web application in which users are communicating to each other concurrently. My coworker and I have been trying to represent this in the Arquillian testing framework by creating a pool of threads during one of the tests, but we have been running into issues and I haven't been able to find any examples online so far.

Comment: Technically it is possible. But with that small amount of details it's hard for me to point you into the right direction. Ideally if you could share the sample project through github or sth similar I can try to hack around and make a pull request. It sounds quite interesting :)

Comment: It looks like we are just going to be ignoring that for now and basically hoping for the best. Not my favorite strategy, but we have decided to focus efforts elsewhere for now. Thank you for your input though!

Sorry for the delayed reply, thought I already posted it a while back.